# How to use ArrayList in heapsort

Tags: java, arraylist, heap, heapsort

I'm trying to implement heapsort using ArrayList. I'm not familiar with using ArrayList, but here is what I came up with for one method of my program, maxHeap:

I'm not sure if I'm making use of the `array.get(element)` method correctly. I know you're supposed to use that method to retrieve the value at the element, but in this case, if I wanted to set `largest = left`, would I be putting it as `arr.get(largest) = arr.get(left)`? Or would I make use of the `array.set()` method?

```
public class Heaps 
{
   public void maxHeap(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int index, int size)
   {

    int largest = index;            // Largest index
    int left = (2*index) + 1;       // Left Child node
    int right =(2*index) + 2;       // Right Child node
    size = arr.size();              // Size of array                        

    if ((left < size) && (arr.get(left) > arr.get(largest)))
        {               
            largest = left;
        }
    else 
        {
            largest = index;                    
        }
    if ((right < size) && (arr.get(right) > arr.get(largest)))  
        {
            largest = right;
        }
    if (largest != index)                       
        {   
           // Swap element at index with element at largest
            Collections.swap(arr, arr.get(index), arr.get(largest));
            maxHeap(arr, largest, size);        // Recursive call
        }
    }


  public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Heaps h = new Heaps();

    int n = 5;

    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer> (n);

    Integer a[] = new Integer[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        array.add(a[i]);
    }


    array.add(0, 30);
    array.add(1, 10);
    array.add(2, 16);
    array.add(3, 17);
    array.add(4, 19);

    h.maxHeap(array, 0, array.size());
    System.out.print(array);


    }
}
```

Output of this should be a max heap of the values, eg: `30, 19, 17, 16, 10`
Actual output is the same array entered: `30, 10, 16, 17, 19`
So basically, `maxHeap` didn't work. I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong for the `maxHeap` method.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you're passing `size` in as a parameter and then immediately overwriting it with `arr.size()`. How are you calling this function? What's the expected output given some input, and how does your output differ? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @LAD I didn't see any significant improvement in the update. It added indentation problems of its own and basically imposed a style on the post that wasn't the author's intention. OP is using [GNU/Whitesmiths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Brace_placement_in_compound_statements) style braces which seems entirely appropriate. My complaints are `=(2*index)` (incorrect spacing) and `arr.get(largest))` is a compiler error, missing `)`. The function indentation doesn't match the conditional blocks, but seems minor.

Comment: @ggorlen Ok, I guess the edit wasn't formatted the best either.

Comment: @ggorlen please review edited post, I added the driver method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not approaching a complicated problem when you have not used `ArrayList` much in the past. Using [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/) I have fixed your code.

---

```
public static class Heaps { // Static class so you can access it through the main class.

    public void maxHeap(ArrayList<Integer> array, int index, int size) {

        int largest = index; // Root Node
        int left = 2 * index + 1; // Left Child node
        int right = 2 * index + 2; // Right Child node

        if (left < size && array.get(left) > array.get(largest)) {
            largest = left;
        }
        if (right < size && array.get(right) > array.get(largest)) {
            largest = right;
        }

        if (largest != index) {
            Collections.swap(array, index, largest); // Swap the indexes not the values
            maxHeap(array, largest, size);
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Heaps h = new Heaps(); // Not edited, but I would recommend static methods for this example

    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Arrays are automatically resized, no need to make an empty array, etc.

    array.add(30);
    array.add(10);
    array.add(16);
    array.add(17);
    array.add(19);
    array.add(50);
    array.add(70);
    array.add(86);
    array.add(7);
    array.add(-2);

    int size = array.size();

    // Prerequisites for max heap sorting.

    for(int i = size / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        h.maxHeap(array, i, size);
    }

    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Collections.swap(array, i, 0);
        h.maxHeap(array, 0, i);
    }

    System.out.print(array);
    // Output: [-2, 7, 10, 16, 17, 19, 30, 50, 70, 86]
    // Time: 284549 nanoseconds

}
```